# File include in Yii

Tags: php, yii, solarium

I am trying to extend my yii application with solarium extension (extension for solr in php) .

However , the library for the extension had multiple sub directories . As a result I have to include files from specific sub directories like this :

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.Library.Solarium.*');
Yii::import('application.extensions.Library.Solarium.Client.*');
Yii::import('application.extensions.Library.Solarium.Client.RequestBuilder.*');
```

This leads to ugly code as well as unpredictability if I have included all files or not .Though I am doing this in the action currently I will move it to config later for production . Is there any other convenient way to include all files from the directories and sub directories ? There are a lot of sub directories and so mentioning each one would lead into 20-30 lines of code . One option is to place all library files in  a single directory for production . However I am not sure if it would affect functionality (I am generically 'new' to implementing extensions/libraries) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i'm adding 3rd party classes to Yii, i put them in a folder under  `protected/components/`, like `/protected/components/solr`.

Then in the main configuration i add the following lines to the **import** section:

```
'import' => array(
      'application.components.solr.*',
      ...
```

But you need to add each subfolder one by one, this is due to perfomance issues, Yii's developers removed recursive import some releases ago. If you think that'll sucks, then you can use **namespaces** to do what you want, but you'll need PHP 5.3

Comment: I am moving all the files under a single directory , at least the ones I am using , I will have to test it out to see if it throws a bug for some case .